# Android - File provider - Send file via email

Tags: android, email-attachments, android-fileprovider

I am currently looking for a way to save a file in the internal memory of my device, and then to send it by mail. For this, I use *FileProvider*

So on the Android Manifest, I add those lines in my manifest :

```html
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="exploration.syte.fr.sendbymail4.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />

    </provider>
```

And on res/xml path I added this file path : *paths.xml*

```html
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="files" path="files/"/>

</paths>
```

Here is the code I use to create my file - a really simple text file that contains the word "test".

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  String textToWrite = "test";
  try {
    File path = this.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(path, "myfile.txt");
    String chemin = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
    Log.i("MainActivity", chemin);
    Toast.makeText(this, chemin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(textToWrite.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    //Toast.makeText(this, "File correctly saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Main", "Exception", e);
  }
  try {
    sendFile(this);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Main", "Exception", e);
  }
}
```

And the code I use to send the file via e-mail

```js
 public static void sendFile(Context context){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String directory=(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())/*+File.separator+"directory"*/);
        File file=new File(directory+File.separator+"myfile.txt");

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "exploration.syte.fr.sendbymail4.fileprovider", file);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**The problems that i am currently encoutering are : **

- My file is not save in the correct directory : it is save on `/data/user/0/exploration.syte.fr.sendbymail4/files/myfile.txt`

And I want my file to be save on : `/data/data/exploration.syte.fr.sendbymail4/files/myfile.txt`

How can I set the path were the file is save correctly ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: *My file is not save in the correct directory* **well, it is a correct path**... why you wana path at all if you are using FileProvider?

Comment: Maybe there's something I did not understand then... How can I save my file using FileProvider ?

Comment: It's all in documentation ... Didn't you forgot about "files" in your path ? the path should be "files/files/myfile.txt" it is obvious when you take a look at the docs: from xml `files-path` means that `getFilesDir()` (app/files) should be used but there is another files in xml `path="files/"` (app/files/files)

Comment: The problem was there... I change my path from "files/" to "/" and it worked.Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I will save the image

```
    public static String saveImage(Context context, Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
//        String root = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root + subFolder);
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(myDir, dateFilenameFormat.format(new Date()) + ".jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            downScale(finalBitmap).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return file.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

file_provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

And send (work for getFilesDir or getFilesDir from "cache" or "files" dirs)

```
public static void sendEmail(String attachmentFile, String message, Context context) {
try {
    String email = "myname@gmail.com";
    String subject = "subject";
    final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // generate URI, I defined authority as the application ID in the Manifest, the last param is file I want to open
    File file = new File(attachmentFile);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending email..."));
    /*
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending email..."));
    }
    */
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.d(TAG, t.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

}